# Store reference for a document in another collection in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
collection-1
                |--{auto-generated-id-1}
                                  |--property1:value1
                                  |--property2:value2
                                  |--peoperty3:value3
```

I have a *collection-1* which stores numerous properties for a document. I want to create another collection, *collection-reference* with the same ID from the earlier collection and store **one important property** for faster lookup

How do I do this in Firebase databases?

```
collection-reference
                |--{same auto-generated-id-from above}
                                  |--peoperty3:value3
```

Comment: Please differentiate correctly between firebase (realtime) database and firestore.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [set a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document). If the document doesn't exist, firestore will create a new document with the id provided by you. So in your case, it should be:

```
db.collection("collection-reference").doc("your-uid").set({
    property3: "value3"
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

Comment: Hey is there a way to do this other than placing the code you wrote inside the then()? Like without nesting it?

Comment: Don't know what exactly you mean by nesting... No nesting is involved in async await

Comment: Yes. You can either use ```async - await``` or ```then - catch```. Did you know you can also chain then blocks? ```db.collection('c').get().then(() => {return someNewPromise}).then(() => {return anotherPromise}).then(() => {do soomething}).catch(err => {log error})``` the catch block should only go at the end of the last then block. You must return a ```Promise``` at the end of the previous then block for the next then block to be executed.